# Indian residing in Switzerland travelling to Cancun Mexico

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, mexico

I am an Indian passport holder residing in Switzerland with a B permit. Going by the information online I assumed I do not require a visa to travel to Mexico as a resident of a Schengen area country. Is this incorrect?
This is urgent, could someone please let me know asap.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a valid visa issued
>   by [...] a Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of 180 days

and

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a **permanent**
>   residence permit issued by Switzerland for a maximum stay of
>   180 days.

A B permit is **not** permanent; as such you **do** need a visa.

Comment: Hi @Coke, Thanks for this confirmation. This is really unfortunate because even someone with a tourist visa to Switzerland can travel to Mexico without a Mexican visa, but someone with a legal residency of 5 years in Switzerland is not permitted. It seems to be a crack which I have unfortunately fallen into. Ive had to cancel my year end holiday at the very last minute.

Comment: @user71818 Yeah, sorry about that :/

Comment: @user71818 Don't forget to get a refund of the airport taxes for the flight from the company you booked through. The taxes are **always** refundable as long as you cancel the ticket or don't board the flight.